# Sobolev embedding for functions with time variable

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $1\leq q \leq\infty$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a smooth bounded domain, and $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval. Define
\begin{align*}
W^{2,1}_{q}(\Omega\times I):=\{u:\Omega\times I\to\mathbb{R}\,|\,\|u\|_{L^{q}(\Omega\times I)}<\infty,\|Du\|_{L^{q}(\Omega\times I)}<\infty, \|D^{2}u\|_{L^{q}(\Omega\times I)}<\infty,\|\partial_{t}u\|_{L^{q}(\Omega\times I)}<\infty \}
\end{align*}
Here $D$ is the derivative of spatial variables in $\Omega$.

At the very least, I know that the usual Sobolev space $W^{1,q}(\Omega\times I)\subset C^{0;\alpha}(\Omega\times I)$ (where $\alpha\in(0,1)$ for sufficiently large $p>N$). Now, the question is : "**Can we obtain better regularity for the spatial variables in $\Omega$?**"

For instance, is it true that
\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_{t\in I}\bigg(\|u(t)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}+\|Du(t)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}+\sup\limits_{x,y\in\Omega\\x\neq y}\frac{|Du(x,t)-Du(y,t)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \bigg)<\infty?
\end{align*}
In other words, does it hold that $W^{2,1}_{q}(\Omega\times I)\subset L^{\infty}(I;C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega))$?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much!